# How does document.getElementById() search the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, search

I know some browsers (most today?) make a Hash table of all elements with an ID. So in this case a call to document.getElementById() could just search the Hash table. But how will it do this otherwise in the context of the DOM tree - is it a depth first search for example?

I'm asking because I want to know where the quickest place to put a DOM element would be, so it is found in a search as soon as or close to when the search itself starts.

Had a quick look and could not find any info on this subject specifically.

Much obliged for any help.

Comment: Unless your users are using Netscape I don't think you have to worry about that. I remember vaguely IE6 having issues with the hashtable being the same for ID's and names, and I think IE5 used a hashtable as well, so it's not really an issue.

Comment: @adeneo - thanks for legacy IE info...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since DOM implementation is browser dependent thing, every browser may implement it in a different manner. There is also a chance that browser do have a hash map for all IDs and performs `document.getElementById` using it.

In order to understand in which order browser looks up in the DOM, you can take a look at `document.all` collection that contains plain list of all DOM elements in the `document`. In case of Chrome, Safari and Firefox it seems to be DFS.

Another interesting question is: if two elements in the same document have the same ID, which one will be returned by `document.getElementById`. Using the snippet below it is possible to see, that it is the first element found using DFS algorithm (at least in the browsers mentioned bellow).

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div id="id" data-index="DFS"></div>
</div>
<div id="id" data-index="BFS"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
console.log(document.getElementById('id').getAttribute('data-index'));
```

**Console Output**

```
DFS
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/jaUolyxwrZcXsNXwkmtm?p=preview

***Edit:***

Regarding additional question in the comment to the answer

> I am not sure if the search will stop at the location of the first result, which would of course be quicker...is there a way to test this at all?

Below you can find a code snippet that creates 10000 elements one inside another and one sibling element. In one case the same ID is set to the deepest element and sibling element, in another to all elements. The second case is ~10x time faster than the first one. This proves that the search stops after the first element with matching ID is found.

**JavaScript**

```
function Div(el) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    el.appendChild(div);
    return div;
}

var i, body, el, t0, t1;

el = body = document.querySelector('body');
for(i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    el = new Div(el);
    el.setAttribute('id', 'ix'); // <- setting id="id" in this line will produce ~10x time difference
}
el.setAttribute('id', 'id');

el = new Div(body);
el.setAttribute('id', 'id');

t0 = performance.now();
document.getElementById('id');
t1 = performance.now();

console.log('Time to find element by ID: ' + (t1 - t0) + 'ms');
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/jmGRJvq0qB7qMyyMULhz?p=info

Comment: Thanks - this is a great answer with testable results too! I notice in Chrome you can have multiple instances of the same ID and it will still apply a style (contrary to W3 standards?) but as to which element it will choose I will need to test...but I think you have answered this one already ;)

Comment: Out of interest could a cascade be happening here - so the first it in fact finds is 'BFS' but the final result of the search is 'DFS' - I am not sure if the search will stop at the location of the first result, which would of course be quicker...is there a way to test this at all?

Comment: @user1360809 See edit of my post. It proves that the search stops after first element with matching ID is found.

Comment: WOW! Amazing, you Sir deserve a medal.

Comment: Have another test of my own that I will try out later - create a single set like yours (heavily nested + one sibling) but all have a unique ID, then do a search for items with an ID attribute and put in an array - the array will list in order the elements it has found. Might not prove the getElementById() itself as a different search algorithm might be used to find elements with attributes - some comparisons may be in order...I could call each element with getElementById() and time how quickly results were found then place in an ordered array maybe...

Comment: Just to add to this - It appears W3 HTML5 specifies that: "The term tree order means a pre-order, depth-first traversal of DOM nodes involved (through the parentNode/childNodes relationship)." http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dom-trees