# Does IE11 use a hash-table to optimize document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, getelementbyid

Does IE11 use a hash-table to optimize calls to `document.getElementById()` or if not, what kind of optimization is used? My logic is that `document.getElementById()` will be called fairly often and a full traversal of the DOM tree would be inefficient, so it would make sense to optimize it.

I am asking about a specific browser and a specific method in order for my question to be answerable.

Comment: I'd expect this to be the case but I don't know where to look to see if it's true or not. In general, browsers have always optimised fetching an item by ID. In fact, it was Microsoft's idea to even attach the IDs to the `window` object. Which means that if you have an element with ID `myElement` you'd find a `window.myElement` entry with said element. That was later made into a standard. That comes from the earlier days of IE, which shows the effort for optimising access. I sincerely doubt they do a full scan nowadays with IE11.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we'll have to hope a Microsoft engineer stumbles upon this question :)

Comment: You can generate two different pages with different number of DIVs. Measure the time needed to get one of the DIVs by id on both pages. If a hash-table is used under the hood, the time should not depend on the number of DIVs.

Comment: IE/Edge MVP here. I'll pass it on to the team and see if anyone has any insights!

Comment: It is almost inconceivable that IDs are not hashed, in every browser, not just IE11 - we know from [18-years-old articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS?redirect=no) that ID-based CSS rules are the most performant.

Comment: Without a comment from Microsft, I'm not sure we'll know how this happens, but you might want to check out [How does document.getElementById() search the DOM tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30371455/238322) as the answer there gets into some details.

Comment: Since you mentioned IE 11 just as an example, you could have a look at the source code of Chromium, which is the base of Google Chrome and is open source.

Comment: Just go to a [quite big page](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) check the time it takes to get the last element with an id using different methods (on given link the last `id` is `sec-E`). You should see a difference of about 5ms when using hash-map lookup vs traversal (And this is how I learnt Chrome does use the hashmap for `'#id'`, and `[id=id]`, whereas FF only does for `#id` when using `querySelector()`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it does. Please check this [beautiful article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction) describing the internals of browers. Now to verify this in IE11, if you examine the window object, you'll see a the controls referenced by id. For example, instead of directly doing a

```
var control = document.getElementById("#id")
```

you can directly do a

```
var control = window["id"]
```

and get a reference to the element.

Comment: i think you mean `window["id"]`? tried on chrome it works.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Edited the answer.

Comment: This does not prove that IE handles this internally with a hash table. API != implementation detail